# VB.NET WPF How to center multiple controls in window/forms?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, format, controls, margin

I am much more familiar with WinForms as it is not so punishing. In WinForms, you can select 3 controls right away and click Format > Align > Center in form and bam! Job done.

But in WPF I am not able to find it in the Format tab anymore. So was wondering if I overlooked it somewhere? Have been searching google for hours already and finally decided to ask here.

Here is a picture to further explain my question.
If I choose Middles, the controls will overlap one another. How can I make sure all 3 will be centered nicely in the form/grid/groupbox?

**QUESTION 2** = Also how can I make sure the textboxes have equal space between one another instead of calculating the position every single time?
[image]

Comment: If you use the layout system properly, you will find that many things are actually easier. In this case, you are looking for `HorizontalAlignment`. And put your three controls in a grid with three columns to make the spacing even.

Comment: If you are _calculating positions_ of your controls, you are probably doing it wrong.  In WPF you should not be setting the X, Y properties of any objects to position them.  Use the various layout controls (grid, stackpanel, etc) and the Margin, Padding, and alignment properties (among others) to create your layout.  You have to think differently than with WinForms.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The horizontalAlignment are all set to "left" by default. I have already added a grid with both stretch for the alignment in the groupbox.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am aware that I am doing it wrong that is why I decided to ask here because it is a little tedious to calculate it every time. I am using grid in the groupbox and I am not sure how to position it correctly. There are not many tutorials that can be found online regarding this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WPF you have to think differently.  I created the following Window.xaml that hopefully illustrates what I mean.  I have grids within grids (gridception?) to get things aligned properly.  I use StackPanels for some controls.  There are no calculations that need to be made when resizing.  I added some colors just to show where the different grids are.

[image: Sample Xaml with grids]

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="ThrowAwayWpfApplication.Window2"
        Title="Window2" Height="480" Width="640">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label>Development Type</Label>                
                <ComboBox Margin="5,2,5,2"></ComboBox>
                <Label>Development Type</Label>
                <ComboBox Margin="5,2,5,2"></ComboBox>
                <Label>Development Type</Label>
                <ComboBox Margin="5,2,5,2"></ComboBox>
                <Label>Development Type</Label>
                <ComboBox Margin="5,2,5,2"></ComboBox>
                <Label>Development Type</Label>
                <ComboBox Margin="5,2,5,2"></ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Aqua">
                <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Label>Permanent Number</Label>                
                <TextBox Margin="5,2,5,2" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Label>Quotation Number</Label>
                <TextBox Margin="5,2,5,2" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Label>Invoice Number</Label>
                <TextBox Margin="5,2,5,2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When setting the heights/widths of columns/rows, you can also use percentages to make one row always take up 20% of the height of the grid:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height=2*></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Ah I see what you meant. But I wanted to keep the textboxes below short and centered nicely in the form. Instead of increasing the width to cover up the width of the form, is there an easy way to achieve that?

Comment: You could add a 4th column to that sub grid and play around with the widths using the percentage method I added to the answer to get the proportions right.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a bunch. Gotta play around with stackpanels then because I only used Grid so far as it already does what I wanted all the time.

Comment: There's also a DockPanel that might be useful.

Comment: Yeah I rarely touch other than Grid because whenever I use it, it just messes up all my form. Worse, sometimes control Z wont even help to save it and I need to do it all again.

Comment: To keep the text boxes centered, you can have 5 column in that sub grid.  Set the widths for the first and last columns to "*" and set the widths of the grid columns with the text boxes to absolute sizes.  I think this is one instance where an absolute value (for the grid columns) might be acceptable.